# How do I play multiplayer in myminecraft PE world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I created a paintball game in my world and I noticed squares that are bodies of water which I did not add myself. How is it possible? Can other people enter my world without permission?
Note that my world does not have a seed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No they can not. You must purchase multiplayer for minecraft pe then click host game then your game will be open to the public. If you are playing with friends at your house you have to connect to the same wifi area to play. The water spawns within worlds.